# How do I allocate text to page when link is clicked using PHP?

Tags: php, html, string, hyperlink, href

A link is applied to the text "14 + 16," I can't seem to find similar tasks online where when the link is clicked, the query string is used to allocate text next to the question to finish the answer.

What are some good approaches to get this accomplished using PHP? I just started learning the basics a few days ago.

```
<p>The link below comes back to this same page, with a querystring added to the URL.</p>

<p>Finish the question (answer only appears when you click on the link):</p>

<p><a href="?n1=14&n2=16">14 + 16 = 

<?php



?>

</a></p>
```

Comment: `$_GET['n1'] + $_GET['n2']` maybe?

Comment: So do you want to update the page with the result of the calculation when the user clicks it? This sounds like a task for client-side Javascript, not any server-side language.

Comment: I see... but I'm required to use php for this task. user3783243 may be on the right track on what I need to do

Answer (score 1):

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["n1"])  +  $_GET['n2'];
```

seemed to accomplished what I needed. If anyone has any other approaches, I would love to learn/see.